# Hashing v encrypting of passwords

Tags: c#, password-encryption

I'm looking for folks thoughts on hashing v encrypting as is done in this article

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Username-or-Password-stored-in-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

I had previously used hashing on SQL passwords which I thought worked quite well.  Is one better than the other?  Should this not be used due to the same encryption key being used?  Any opinions welcome, thanks

Comment: With the current phrasing, this is a very subjective question. Can you think of a different phrasing that'd make it less opinion-based (which is off-topic for SO)?

Comment: Do NOT EVER store passwords in a database, encrypted or not. If the password can be retrieved, it's in danger of being stolen. Use a highly secure hashing algorithm with salt to store only hashes. A good hashing algorithm makes it unfeasible to recover the password in case your database gets hacked into.

Comment: if you encrypt the password, you will have overhead of storing the encryption key.

Comment: I think there is no sane reason to _only_ encrypt. However it's not that trivial with hashing _and_ encryption together.